# Question structure in Esperanto

Tags: questions

Does every question in Esperanto have to be formed with *ĉu* or one of the *ki-* words (*kie*, *kio*, *kiam,*... etc) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is no. This is discussed in [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/demandoj_respondoj/demandoj_sen_demandovorto.html), section 22.3, *Demandoj sen demandovorto*.

They normally take one of two forms:

- Sentence fragments, usually 2-3 words: *Via nomo? Efektive? Sed la teo?*
- Declarative statements with doubtful nuance: *Do vi ne deziras teon? Kaj pro tio vi perdis la bileton?*

In these situations the question-word is being omitted for the sake of conversational neatness: they could be rephrased as *Kio estas via nomo? Ĉu efektive? Sed kiel estu la teo traktata?* etc.

Comment: How about the following?  Would this be incorrect: "Ŝatas lerni?  Volas lerni alian lingvon?" I saw someone post something similar to this on Facebook a while back. It seems the subject "You" is implied.

Comment: It is permissible if the intended subject is really obvious. However, it cannot be done all the time, as the absence of a subject can change the meaning of the sentence: for example, *Ŝi estas infano* means "She is a child" but *Estas infano* means "There's a child."

Comment: I understand. The person who posted that way had mentioned elsewhere that he was fluent in Esperanto, so I thought maybe he knew something I didn't.