# Can you ask questions without 'ĉu'?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to ask a question in Esperanto without 'ĉu,' or is this strictly grammatically incorrect? Especially in speech comes to mind, when asking with an inflection.

Comment: Do you also mean without using any specific questions words? (e.g. "Kie estas la librejo?")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question structure in Esperanto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/question-structure-in-esperanto)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Many questions are formed using the [interrogative correlatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogatives_in_Esperanto#Correlative_interrogatives)(*kio*, *kiu*, *kial* etc.). Examples are

- *Kial vi ploras?*  (Why are you crying?)
- *Vi faris kion?* (You did what?)

It is also possible to construct sentences without *ĉu* or any of the interrogative correlatives, see [Question structure in Esperanto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/question-structure-in-esperanto).